# Define rotational anchor point in the center of a quad shape in p5js

Tags: p5.js

I know that there is `rectMode(CENTER)` of both rectangles and ellipses, but what about other shapes like triangles and quad shapes?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be hard to write a long reply because the answer is **no**, there isn't a `rectMode()` for triangles or shapes you create using the `quad()` or `vertex()` functions.

You could use the `translate()` function to translate to the center of the shape, and then draw all of the points relative to that. That would also solve the question that I think you're trying to ask about then calling the `rotate()` function.

Comment: Damn, thought so. I'll need to write a custom function for it. Thanks!